# R - How to download ascii raster and unzip it?

Tags: r, ascii, raster

I'm trying to download an ascii raster and unzip it using R:

```
require(raster)
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("http://goo.gl/yGC4GU",temp)
myRaster <- raster( unz(temp, "koppen_ascii.txt") )
```

but I get the following error message:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘raster’ for signature ‘"unz"’
```

Is there any alternative method?

Comment: Separate the unzipping from the reading. raster needs a file name, not the output of unz

Comment: Maybe you can find useful hints even in [gis.stackexchange.com](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r+raster)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unzip your file to the working folder and then read it:

```
> unzip(temp)
> myRaster = raster("./koppen_ascii.txt")
```

use `tempdir()` to create a temp directory and pass it as the `exdir` option to `unzip` if you want to save it elsewhere.

```
> zipd = tempdir()
> unzip(temp, exdir=zipd)
> myRaster = raster(file.path(zipd,"koppen_ascii.txt"))
```