# Open .gz compressed ASCII raster in R

Tags: r, raster

I am trying to open and process in R the raster data stored as `asc.gz` file: ASCII and .gz compressed, as weather data [here](https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/grids_germany/monthly/precipitation/01_Jan/). I need to extract the weather data for each location for every year and every month = many values, so I wish to automate the process and not upzipp the files manually.

I have followed the previous suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24406923/r-how-to-download-ascii-raster-and-unzip-it) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42088695/r-read-geotiff-from-gz-file-with-a-connection-and-raster-package) how to open a `.gz` compressed file, and then the raster one. But I get errors like:

```
Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.

unable to find an inherited method for function ‘raster’ for signature ‘"gzfile"’
```

How to succesfully open the .gz compressed ASCII file in R?

Until now I have tried (not working):

```
ras_path = paste(myPath, 'rawData/DeutschWetter/01_Jan',  "200501asc.gz", sep = "/")
connect=gzfile(ras_path)  
r=raster::raster(connect)
```

Using the `temp` folder:

```
temp <- tempfile()

unzip(temp)
r=raster::raster(ras_path)

zipd = tempdir()
unzip(temp, exdir=zipd)
myRaster = raster(ras_path)
```

Trying to read [raster as a raw vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42088695/r-read-geotiff-from-gz-file-with-a-connection-and-raster-package):

```
# create connection to a gz file
con <- gzfile(ras_path, open = "rb")

# read data from this connection into a raw vector
myras.raw <- readBin(con, what = "raw", n = 1e10)

# read this raw vector
myras <- raster(con)
```

I am using R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10).

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764499/decompress-gz-file-using-r) for a general discussion of decompressing gz files.

In this case, you can directly read the files you point at like this (I am using the "terra" package, the replacement of the "raster" package)

```
library(terra)
url <- "https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/grids_germany/monthly/precipitation/01_Jan/grids_germany_monthly_precipitation_188101.asc.gz"
x <- rast(paste0("/vsigzip//vsicurl/", url))
```

Or first download the file

```
f <- basename(url)
download.file(url, f, mode="wb")
y <- rast(paste0("/vsigzip/", f))
```

Or first decompress the downloaded gz file (and perhaps remove it with `remove=TRUE`)

```
R.utils::gunzip(f, remove=FALSE)
ff <- gsub(".gz$", "", f)
z <- rast(ff)
```

These ascii files do not store the coordinate reference system, so you need to set it yourself.

```
crs(z) <- "EPSG:31467"
z
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 866, 654, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
#extent      : 3280415, 3934415, 5237501, 6103501  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 3 (EPSG:31467) 
#source      : grids_germany_monthly_precipitation_188101.asc 
#name        : grids_germany_monthly_precipitation_188101
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you so much! also, thank you for including `terra` package, it is way faster than the `raster` one. Is the `"EPSG:31467"` typical for German weather data, or is it just a randomly selected one?

Comment: I took the coordinate reference system from the metadata (BESCHEIBUNG / DESCRIPTION) file in  https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/grids_germany/monthly:/precipitation/

Answer (score 1):

Using the package `R.utils` to uncompress the `.gz` file, you can do something like that:

```r
ras_path <- "<YOUR_PATH>\\grids_germany_monthly_precipitation_188101.asc.gz"

R.utils::gunzip(ras_path, remove = FALSE)

new_ras_path <- gsub("\\.gz$", "", ras_path)

raster::raster(new_ras_path)
#> class      : RasterLayer 
#> dimensions : 866, 654, 566364  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#> resolution : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
#> extent     : 3280415, 3934415, 5237501, 6103501  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : NA 
#> source     : grids_germany_monthly_precipitation_188101.asc 
#> names      : grids_germany_monthly_precipitation_188101 
#> values     : -2147483648, 2147483647  (min, max)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>